# Icons should stay at the top of the column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a basic [table js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MNBjT/), the icons are obvi font awesome, you can see here that as the right hand side grows with text the icons always stay in the enter, well I want them to stick to the top with a padding of 10 px's.

I am, although not here, using bootstrap. So is there a class to do this? `.table` in bootstrap will pull the icons to the top - but it also adds a top border which I don't want, I could go in and remove that, but I would rather not.

So is there a bootstrap class that will cause all icons to jump to the top of the `tr` element they are in? - or better yet, is there some simple css I could do to make the icon "stick" to the top of the containing `tr` element they are in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this css-property to the TD of the icon:

```
vertical-align:top;
```

This makes sure the icon stays at the top. You could change the position with padding ;)